# AngularJS GET receives empty reply in Chrome but not in Fiddler

Tags: angularjs, wcf, google-chrome, iis, fiddler

I'm implementing file download using AngularJS and WCF. My back-end is a .NET project hosted in IIS. The file is serialized as an array of bytes and then on the client side I utilize the File API to save the content.

To simplify the problem, back-end is like:

```
 [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "FileService?path={path}")]
 [OperationContract]
 public byte[] DownloadFileBaseOnPath(string path)
 {
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
       var fileStream = File.OpenRead(path);
       fileStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
       fileStream.Close();
       WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=\"Whatever\"";  
       WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"; // treat all files as binary file
       return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
 }
```

And on client side, it just sends a GET request to get those bytes, converts in into a blob and save it.

```
 function sendGetReq(url, config) {
    return $http.get(url, config).then(function(response) { 
        return response.data;   
    });
 }
```

Save the file then:

```
 function SaveFile(url) {
     var downloadRequest = sendGetReq(url);
     downloadRequest.then(function(data){
        var aLink = document.createElement('a');
        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(data);
        var blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/octet-stream'});
        var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        aLink.setAttribute('href', downloadUrl);
        aLink.setAttribute('download', fileNameDoesNotMatter);
        if (document.createEvent) {
            var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
            event.initEvent('click', false, false);
            aLink.dispatchEvent(event);
        }
        else {
            aLink.click();
        }
        setTimeout(function () {
            URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl);
        }, 1000); // cleanup
     });
 }
```

This approach works fine with small files. I could successfully download files up to 64MB. But when I try to download a file larger than 64MB, the response.body is empty in Chrome. I also used Fiddler to capture the traffic. According to Fiddler, Back-end has successfully serialized the byte array and returned it. Please refer to the screenshot below.

In this example, I was trying to download a 70MB file:

[image: Request In Fiddler]
[image: Same Request in Chrome]

And the response.data is empty:
[image: Empty Response.data]

Any idea why this is empty for file over 70MB? Though the response itself is more than 200MB, I do have enough memory for that.

Regarding to the WCF back-end, I know I should use Stream Mode when it comes to large files. But the typical use of my application is to download files less than 10MB. So I hope to figure this out first.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Answer my own question.

Honestly I don't know what's going wrong. The issue still persists if I transfer it as a byte array. I eventually gave up this approach by returning a stream instead. Then on the client side, adding the following configuration

```
{responseType : blob}
```

and save it as a blob.